# Insert rails datetime to Oracle column of type DATE

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**My problem:**

I tried adding the datetime parameter from rails to oracle but it still truncates the time

**Example:**

```
order.create!(creation_date: '2022-01-23 23:59:59')
```

**log:**

```
INSERT INTO "order" ("creation_date") Values(:a1)[["creation_date","2022-01-23"]]
```

[Oracle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOaNX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added in incoming TABLE Models:
attribute :{table_column}, :datetime